# Derivative of the infinity norm of a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces

Let $f(\lambda)=\|(A+\lambda I)^{-1}\|_{\infty}$, where $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $A+\lambda I$ is invertible. Moreover, $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is invertible. I wonder if the derivative of $f(\lambda)$ exists and how to find it if it exists?

Comment: $f(\lambda)$ is infinite when $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. Do you mean to ask whether is differentiable for $\lambda$ not an eigenvalue?

Comment: Yes, $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue here. Actually, $\lambda$ is chosen so that $A+\lambda I$ is invertible. Thank you for your comments, I have re-edited the problem to make it more clear.

Comment: The derivative $f'(\lambda)$ does not have to exist for all $\lambda$, even if $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue.